# Building sipXtapi on Generic Linux - Install error

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, sip, automake

I'm trying to install the API `sipXtapi` to work with `recon` with this tutorial:

> https://www.resiprocate.org/Building_recon

But on the third pass **To build sipXmediaLib**, when I make the command:

```
   autoreconf -fi
```

I receive an error:

```
error: 'pkgdatadir' is not a legitimate directory for 'LTLIBRARIES'
```

and i get another error

`error: invalid feature name: local-audio` in sipXmediaLib

Anyone knows the solution for this ? Or any hint ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

---

The sipXtapi you can get with `$ svn checkout http://sipxtapi.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ sipxtapi-read-only`

.. seems to be less buggy than your version `$ svn checkout https://scm.sipfoundry.org/rep/sipX/main sipXtapi`

And then we have "the archive" : https://code.google.com/p/sipxtapi/downloads/list

---

[sipxtapi](/questions/tagged/sipxtapi)

Comment: with that I get this error "Cannot find libpcre.so or libpcre.a libraries - looked in yes/lib". :(

Comment: do you know how to solve "error: invalid feature name: local-audio" in sipXmediaLib?